# API response text to JSON

Tags: python, json, rest, api, django-rest-framework

I'm using an API that returns me this text:

```
HTTP/1.1 0 nullContent-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 02 Nov 2017 10:48:39 GMT
Connection: close

{"codigoRetorno":104,"mensajeRetorno":"ENVIO DUPLICADO, ENCONTRADO MISMO NUMERO DE ENVIO CON FECHA:02/11/2017","datosResultado":null,"listaBultos":null,"etiqueta":null}
```

I use "requests" to use this API:

```
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}

result = requests.post(
    url, data=data,
    auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password),
    headers=headers, verify=False)

result_content = json.loads(result.content)
```

But when I try to format the response to JSON it gives me this error: ***"ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded"***

I guess that the problem is the response is text. What's the best way to solve this problem. I thought about using a regular expression but maybe there is another method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a better way, but you can always use with a regular expression.

```
import json

def get_json_from_string(string):
    json_string = re.search("{(.*?)}$", string).group(0)
    return json.loads(json.dumps(json_string))
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a built in JSON decoder in requests. You may have more luck using result.json()

Comment: You are better off trying to get it working with the built in decoder. Does that give you the same error message?

Comment: I get this error: "simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"

Comment: That implies there is no JSON/the response is invalid. I am guessing json.loads(response.text) fails too?

Comment: Yes. It fails too

Comment: I would verify that result.encoding is actually utf-8. Other than that, if you have control over the API you are calling, I would try a very basic response to see if it is failing in other scenarios. Would also try without specifying headers on the post. Good luck!